# Address a property of parent ListView from a listview item

Tags: wpf

Desired: set border properties of a listview depending on conditions in displayed items. For example:

Set the border of an entire ListView red if any one of its (string) items begins  with "S". So the problem is how to address a parent listview from its items (within xaml preferably)
Something like

```
<ListView Name="lv" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TheItemList}" Height="100" BorderBrush="Black">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding }">
    <TextBlock.Style>
     <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolean}} 
        Value="True">
        <Setter ???? Value="Red"/>
       </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
   </TextBlock>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

(where the converter is the obvious thing) does not work: I can' use
`TargetName="lv"` in the ???? part of the setter, that's outside the scope. Neither can I use `<Style TargetType="ListView">` in the style declaration. I could of course go up and back through the view model, but how does one do this in .xaml?

Must be having a bad day, this seems like an obvious thing. My googling hasn't yielded much unfortunately.

Comment: You won't do it like this. But why do you want to validate the values in the ListView? Instead of binding to invalid data you must validate it before exposing it. Where do the values come from?

Comment: Not really validation going on in the actual situation. The code is just an illustration. I wanted to take advantage of the bindings in the .xaml instead of having to write a bunch of events in code.

Answer (score 1):

A setter in a `Style` can only set a property of the element to which the `Style` is applied, i.e. a `Style` for a `TextBlock` cannot set the property of the parent `ListView`.

You could "move" the `Style` to the `ListView` and implement the converter to return `true` if `ListBox.Items.OfType<string>().Any(x => x?.StartsWith("s") == true)` or something similar.

But a `Style` for a child element cannot set a property of the parent element.